# How to map two String[] to each other

Tags: java, android, string, dictionary

I'm developing an Android app. I'm mapping two arrays to each other with a HashMap. I change these arrays into String[]'s, and map them together. It should return values, but it returns null. I'm not sure where I'm going wrong. I've searched online, but I haven't found anything useful. My code is below:

**Part of StationList.java**

```
Spinner2.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() {

        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1,
                int arg2, long arg3) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                String selectedValue = arg0.getItemAtPosition(arg2).toString();

                String[] Yellow_ID = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.Yellow_ID);
                String[] Yellow_Li = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.Yellow_Line);

                Map<String[], String[]> myMap = new HashMap<String[], String[]>();
                    myMap.put(Yellow_Li, Yellow_ID);

                String[] value = myMap.get(selectedValue);
                tv12.setText(String.valueOf (value));




        }
```

`Value` returns null in the `TextView`. I think this is due to the values not mapping to each other. I would appreciate any help you could give me.

Comment: Your map keys are of type `String[]`, and you are fetching value for `String` key. Why did you expect that to return you something apart from `null`. It would be much better if you could explain what you exactly want to do.

Comment: @RohitJain That explains it! How would I convert String selectedValue to String[] selected?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Based on how you're retrieving your value, you want to do something more like this when populating your hashmap

```
Map<String, String> myMap = new HashMap<String, String>();
for (int i = 0; i < Yellow_Li.length(); i++) {
     myMap.put(Yellow_Li[i], Yellow_ID[i]);
}
String value = myMap.get(selectedValue);
```

I assume the String arrays are the same size so if they are not you should add that logic in.

Also, if the arrays are the same size you could so something like this so you don't have to build a hashmap:

```
int index = -1;
for (int i = 0; i < Yellow_Li.length(); i++) {
    if (Yellow_Li[i].equals(selectedValue)) {
        index = i;
        break;
    }
}

String value = Yellow_ID[index]; //should do a check for -1 before you try to assign "value"
```

Comment: For the iterator on the first option, how can I do that if I have String[]'s, not Strings?

Comment: You mean arg0.getItemAtPosition(arg2) returns a String[] ? If so, what's contained in there? How do you plan to compare them? do each of the values need to be the same?

Comment: It's just the item selected on the spinner. The problem with this is that Yellow_Li[i] equals a String, not a String[], and I have my arrays set to equal String[]'s, so it does not resolve correctly.

Comment: @hichris123 Yes, but the way I have posted compares each individual String in your String[] to the String returned from your spinner.  You're trying to see if the String from the spinner exists in Yellow_Li.. and if it exists in Yellow_Li, get the value at the same index from Yellow_ID.. correct?

Comment: Correct, but it says `The method put(String[], String[]) in the type Map<String[],String[]> is not applicable for the arguments (String, String)`.

Comment: Did you change how you construct the HashMap 'myMap'? Look at the args I put into it. They are Strings where as in yours you have String[]. If you change it to Map<String, String> myMap = new HashMap<String, String>(); it will work

Answer (score 1):

What you're doing is creating a single entry in the map, where the key value is the reference to the first String array object and the associated value is the reference to the second String array object. The map doesn't contain a collection of entries, where I'm assuming you're trying to map values in one array (keys) to values in the second array (values) and then perform a lookup on the key.

You need to iterate through the String arrays and for each iteration put a new entry in the map where the key is the element in the first string array and the value is the element in the second string array. Then you'll end up with what you want.

Answer (score 0):

The problem your approach is that the `equals` method for an array uses object identity.  That makes them unsuitable for use as `Map` keys.  Specifically, `Map.get` will only give you a match (i.e. return a non-`null` reference) if you supply the *original* key array as the key parameter.  Not another array with elements that are index-by-index `equal` to the original array elements.

You are also (apparently) using the wrong keys when you attempt to lookup colours.  You are doing the `get` with a `String` rather than a `String[]`.

Having said that, your approach *might* work if ...

- you actually used a `String[]` as a key, AND
- you obtained that `String[]` in a way that ensures that the key object is that same object.

Answer (score 0):

You are using a `Map` with key type `String[]` and value type `String[]`. But the key, you are using to retrieve the value is of type `String` (not `String[]`). So it will probably not have the same hashcode as a String-Array even with only one String.

Comment: So then how can I convert the String to String[]?

Comment: String[] strings = new String[] { selectedValue }